# Unsubscribing from subscription

Tags: javascript, botkit

Subscribing to all messages:

```
controller.hears('', ['direct_message'], function (bot, message) {
    //handlign message
});
```

Is it possible to unsubscribe from all messages? Replacing handler function with null doesn't give anything. Documentation surprisingly empty.

Comment: I don't believe this functionality exists, was nothing in the code that would suggest it did either. You could potentially do this yourself by manipulating `controller.events`.

Comment: @DavidBarker Thanks, I'll look at `events`. But it's really strange and unclear why there is no such functionality.